# Moving a uploaded file with PHP

Tags: php, html

Here is my file system.

---public_html
-------upload
-----------images(under upload)
-------uploadimage(under public_html)
-------other folder

all my html php js files are in the upload folder, i can upload image to the images folder.
Is there a way i can upload the image to the uploadimage folder ( which is outside of upload folder)

here is my php code for the moving

```
if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
```

when i change images to uploadimage  the server gives warning.

Comment: you can move an uploaded file anywhere you like

Comment: Simply change your upload path of file. Post your code here

Comment: Sorry, I did not state it clearly. images and uploadimage are from different parent folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose any folder you want, just as long as all of them have proper permissions set to them.

Based on example #1 on PHP.net

- **http://php.net/move_uploaded_file**

You will want to use: `../` depending on the file's execution location.

I.e.: `$uploads_dir = '../images/uploadimage';`

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '../uploadimage';
//$uploads_dir = '../images/uploadimage';
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

### Edit, after seeing OP's code

(Code was not initially posted in [`original question`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21837428/1))

and as you edited, being under `public_html` you would do:

```
$uploads_dir = '../uploadimage';
```

So, in your case and using your posted code, you can use the following:

```
if (file_exists("../uploadimage/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../uploadimage/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "../uploadimage/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
```

Comment: You're quite welcome @user3265085